# Include snippets in template that have view-like logic

Tags: flask, flask-flatpages

I am building a blog with flask-flatpages. In the header of a markdown blogpost, I list the related blogpostings by filename. These should show up as excerpts below the actual blogposting.

Here is what blogpost-1.md should look like:

```
title: "Blogpost one"
published: 2014-02-13
related:
    - blogpost-2.md
    - blogpost-4.md
description: "This is the excerpt of blogpost one."

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
vel leo turpis. Cras vulputate mattis dignissim. Aliquam eget
purus purus.
```

And the result I want:

```
BLOGPOST ONE

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vel
leo turpis. Cras vulputate mattis dignissim. Aliquam eget purus purus.

related posts:

BLOGPOST TWO
Summary here

BLOGPOST THREE
Also a summary
```

The essential part is to follow the path of the related blogpostings and render their title and excepts. Naively something like:

```
{% for item in blog.meta.related %}
    <div>
    <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>
    <p>{{ item.decription</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is obviously not going to work, because `meta.related` is simply a list of strings. It is also not difficult to make a view function that takes these strings and returns a httpResponse:

```
# app.py
@app.route('/excerpt/<path:path>.html')
def excerpt(path):
    blog = blogs.get_or_404(path)
    return render_template('excerpt.html', blog=blog)

# excerpt.html
<div>
<h4>{{ blog.meta.title }}</h4>
<p>{{ blog.meta.description }}</p>
</div>
```

My question: how do I make this happen within the same template?

Should I somehow try to pass the data from the related blogpostings into the context: a list of dicts maybe? Should I use a context processor to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei Roy, thanks for you research but for the moment i cannot comment so i have to find a way to clarify this.

In order to make this working, in the markdown file you wrote:

```
title: "Blogpost one"
published: 2014-02-13
related:
- blogpost-2.md
- blogpost-4.md
description: "This is the excerpt of blogpost one."

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
vel leo turpis. Cras vulputate mattis dignissim. Aliquam eget
purus purus.
```

Need to be change *blogpost-2.md and blogpost-4.md* **without the .md** extension. 
Without these changes when you loop on the view file:

```
for path in blog.meta['related']:
        related_list.append(blogs.get_or_404(path))
```

blogpost-1/2.md **will not be added** to your list because Flask-FlatPages will not understand .md extension and 404 error comes up.

In my case

```
@app.route('/blog/<path:path>.html')
```

is changed without .html like :

```
@site.route('/bloging/<path:path>/')
```

And to simplify some coding, in template

```
{{ related.meta.title }}
```

is equivalent to

```
{{ related.title }}
```

and you could add the link to your related article with:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('site.bloging', path=related.path) }}">{{ related.title }}</a>
```

where site is my blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at a pretty straightforward answer, but keeping the question open to see if there is a more elegant solution.

In the view function, I iterate the paths of the related blog postings and add the blog objects to a list, which gets passed to the template.

Like this:

```
@app.route('/blog/<path:path>.html')
def blog_detail(path):
    blog = blogs.get_or_404(path)
    related_list = []
    for path in blog.meta['related']:
        related_list.append(blogs.get_or_404(path))
    return render_template('blog-detail.html', blog=blog, related_list=related_list)
```

And in the template:

```
{% for related in related_list %}
    hoi
    <div>
        <h4>{{ related.meta.title }}</h4>
        <p>{{ related.meta.description }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```